# How can a permutation act on a set if there is no ordering inherent in a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, permutations

I'm hoping this isn't a stupid question. I'm currently pondering the notion of a "permutation of a set". For the first time, this idea seemed a little strange to me, because there is no ordering inherent in a set, and I think of a permutation as a reordering.

Perhaps I shouldn't think of permutation as a reordering? Like, a transposition acting on a set would literally be  making an element $\alpha$ into an $a$ and $a$ into an $\alpha$ (where $a,\alpha \in S$).

Like I said, hope this isn't a dumb question, I guess im just aware that I know some people are really into foundations of math and stuff and maybe someone can clarify what's wrong with my thinking....

Comment: You can also think of a permutation as a renaming.  It is just a bijective map from a collection to itself.

Comment: True order doesn't matter in a set. But say the set $\{a,b,c\}$ can be permuted, simply because the elements in this set are distinct. The permutations are simply one-to-one onto functions from the set to itself.

Comment: Just think of it as an *ordering*, not a *re*ordering.

Comment: @Dan: that has the same problem. To define a bijection between permutations and orderings you need to pick a "base" ordering to start with. The situation is exactly analogous to the relationship between invertible linear transformations and bases.

Comment: If it helps, the elements of a set are not necessarily ordered, but they are nonetheless *distinct*. So we can map one element to another one. A permutation is just a mapping where each element gets mapped to some other (or the same) element, and the mapping is bijective.

Comment: So, for a specific set, like $\{ apple, banana, orange\}$, you can talk about sending apple to banana, etc.. But what do you do with a generic set, how do you refer to its elements? The best we can usually do is call them "the first element", "the second element", etc. We're just using the ordered set $1,2,3,...$ to refer to them, but that's all.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: I assume that you mean the first/second/third element *as written*, or the first/second/third element *alphabetically* (which happen to coincide in this case).  A set may not have an *inherent* order, but we can *impose* one arbitrarily to make “an ordered set” (or “a list”).

Comment: @Dan - Yes, my point was that sets don't intrinsically have an ordering, but that we often impose one when we want to refer to their individual elements when they don't have any other distinguishing characteristics .

Comment: The mere act of starting to write them down *creates* a first, second, third... element. It's like we are profoundly serial creatures, and we can't avoid imposing an ordering when we put our hands on things

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A permutation on a set $S$ is a function $f : S \to S$ (which is bijective, but this function thing is what's important here). This doesn't require any notion of order, you just need to say which elements get mapped to which other elements.

Here's a natural-language example: consider the set $S = \{ \text{red}, \text{blue}, \text{yellow} \}$. Then we can consider, for example, the function $f : S \to S$ which swaps red and blue, so $f(\text{red}) = \text{blue}, f(\text{blue}) = \text{red}, f(\text{yellow}) = \text{yellow}$. No ordering necessary.

It is also true that any permutation of a set $S$ *induces* an action on orderings of $S$; for example, the ordering $\text{red}, \text{blue}, \text{yellow}$ gets mapped to the ordering $\text{blue}, \text{red}, \text{yellow}$. But this is a different action from the action on $S$.